# JavaScript: Access HTML element after document.location

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have the body of HTML like this

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
```

And the script

```
<script>
  function myFunction(){
    document.location="https://firstURL.com";
  }

  document.getElementById("edit-submit").onclick = function() {
    userDetailsCollection()
  };

  function userDetailsCollection(){    
     document.location="https://someURL.com";
  }
</script>
```

What I'm trying here is, As soon as page loads for the first time, I'm redirecting to a Url and there I do have a form with a submit button. I want to redirect to one more Url if the submission is proper.

The problem I'm facing is, I'm loosing Js code control in the first onLoad and failing to achieve onClick function in first Url redirection.

How to getElementById("edit-submit").onclick after the first Url redirection? Please suggest.

Comment: Once you redirect to another page, the javascript on the previous page is no longer running/part of the page. You'll have to re-think how you are solving your problem.

Comment: This is not possible.  And if it was, it would represent a horrible security issue.  Imagine if you wanted to do that to collect someone's login information from a login form?

Answer (score -1):

When you do redirection the first time, you can attach data with the URL so you can get data from the first page in the second page.

Hope this help